How do I get started with rtabmap_ros
this is my first post so forgive me for any undersight.
I am using coppeliasim and its quadcopter model equipped with the kinect model to simulate indoor mapping, I can't seem to find the launch file that can help me in so, the documentation seems outdated as well, i.e. the diagram showing the packages of rgbd_sync and rgbd_image_relay are not the ones the nodes are actually in. If anyone can help me choose the launch file that would help me in my simulation that would be great
Thank you!
